# How to remind your boss about vacation time

Tags: communication, time-off

I had a discussion with my boss about leaving early the next day. He said that it is okay with him and I don't need to fill out any paper work since it is a short period of time.

But I want something in writing and just wanted to send him an email reminding him what we discussed.

I need help on sending a more formal email than just saying " hey, based on what we talked about yesterday, I wont be here tomorrow morning."

Comment: your boss is probably not going to make you use up vacation time for this. That's what the reference to not filling out paperwork is about. Your insistence on "getting it in writing" is a good way to ensure you won't get the gift he is trying to give you - time away from the office without using up vacation. What are you trying to prevent by having this written record?

Answer (score 8):

Here is the trick. Write an email about something else so that the boss will think you are a hard worker. For example,

> Boss,
>
> Just wanted to let you know that I'll be dropping off the XYZ project
>   with IR division on Thursday. I won't get a chance to discuss the ABC
>   briefing with Mr. Fulano until Friday since I'll be leaving early
>   today, as we discussed.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just block it out on your calendar, assuming you used shared calendars in Outlook or something similar? Then it is documented.

This is the way I prefer my reports do it. I use our outlook calendars to keep track of who is available and when so it makes sense.

Comment: If only more people would send calendar and task items instead of emails asking if I'm available.